# How can I correct this error since I can now access my hosting space to make the corrections?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem on the display of WordPress site, I can not access the Admin page.

I show you the error message on the display.

Here is the error message:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in /htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 734

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to connect to the administrator page but the same error is displayed.

Here is the message:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in /htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 734

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:734) in /htdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1416

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:734) in /htdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1419

Comment: Sounds like your PHP version is not compatible with your WordPress version.

Comment: Presumably your hosting control panel (e.g. is it cPanel or something like that?) has an option where you can set the PHP version? Most hosts allow you to switch between multiple versions. If not, contact the hosting company for support. If they have changed your PHP version automatically, they should have notified you about this in advance, to give you chance to test your code against the new version, and make any changes/upgrades if necessary. It's possible your code was running on a PHP version which is no longer supported?

Comment: I tried to restore via the host but it still doesn't work. Do you have a solution to propose to me.

Comment: You tried to restore _what_, precisely? Did you ask them whether they had changed the version of PHP which is executing your code, or something like that? If it was working before, and suddenly stopped working, and you had not changed the code, then that is quite a likely cause. Warnings like this might be been suppressed, or only shown as Notices in earlier versions, but newer PHP versions are stricter about what kinds of problematic code they will tolerate.

Comment: FIrst, check the widget because the warning is raised by the conversion from array to string in class-wp-widget.php (probably it tried to concatenate an array with string, or echo an array). If the widget works fine, you may want to suppress warnings from the PHP [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) settings. It depends on the hosting, maybe from cPanel or upload `php.ini` file in your html root directory, or if there is a setting in wordpress

Comment: I asked the hosting company to check their settings because the site was working fine at first. After a few hours the site was displayed but all the information on the page was displayed with difficulty and the WordPress Admin page was still not displayed. I gave them a date when everything was working normally.